# Compare two cells in excel and return the matching string length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-comparison, string-matching, vba

I need to compare two adjacent cells in excel and return the number of character match between the two cells starting from the left most character

The values in column in A and B are as below

```
A1 = Sam Alhoa
A2 = Franklin moore
A3 = Steve jones
A4 = Joe
A5 = Patrick

B1 = Sam Bloggs
B2 = Frank lin dsouza
B3 = Stephen Jones
B4 = Jose
B5 = Patrice
```

The Result in column C should be

```
C1 = 4
C2 = 5
C3 = 3
C4 = 2
C5 = 6
```

What is the excel formula to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this UDF:

```
Function compareCharacters(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Application.Min(Len(s1), Len(s2))
        If Mid(s1, i, 1) <> Mid(s2, i, 1) Then Exit Function
        compareCharacters = compareCharacters + 1
    Next
End Function
```

and call it in any cell like this:

```
=compareCharacters(A1,B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=SUM(IFERROR(IF(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(A1))),1)=MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$" & LEN(B1))),1),1,0),0))`

Entered in C1 as Array Formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: as I understand, OP wants to find number of matching characters starting from left, e.g. for strings `abcde` and `abcee` your formula returns `4`, but seems that should return `3` (as per my understanding of question)

Comment: @simoco haha I was wondrin as well why you `Exit Function` instead of `End If`. The OP wants to count the number of matching characters from left to right but no statement tells to stop counting on the first mismatch. :). I guess what confuses us is the first item which if you count the matching characters including `Space`, it should be `5`.

Comment: as per my approach, comparing `Sam Alhoa` and `Sam Bloggs` gives me `4` (as in OPs example), since `Sam ` (with space) is in both strings. It doesn't take into accoung `l`, since previous characters `A` and `B` are not the same